# Remove extra step of converting blanks to zeros before csv to sql conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, null

I have a **CSV** file, which I want to import to **SQL**. However, I first had to remove the blanks in excel and then do the import to SQL, without which I was getting an error(the column was defined as DECIMAL datatype and was not accepting blanks). I am trying to reduce the number of steps I need to perform in this activity. So, is there an easier way to get rid of blanks, other than manually deleting before converting to SQL?

---

Code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders(
name VARCHAR(6)
email VARCHAR(200)
amount DECIMAL
);

COPY orders(name,email,amount)
FROM '/Users/Documents/ABC/csv/orders_export_1.10.21.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
> CONTEXT:  COPY orders, line 46, column amount: ""
> ```

Comment: Can you not change the data type to varchar and then clean it up in SQL once it's successfully imported?

Comment: Show us the code that you have now that is working. Then we can help you optimize it. The first thing you need is working code.

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using

Comment: @PhilCoulson I get the error when I try to import.  So, I had to clean up before importing. I have copy pasted the error I got.

Comment: @AndyLester sure, I just copy-pasted the code and the error.

Comment: @NickW its PostgreSQL